# problems while rating via selected star images for vision and back end select hidden value of input type radio

Tags: jquery, html, css, default-value, rating

Hi i am trying to get value of input type radio by clicking on a star image by vision
and am success in this but am stuck in resetting the star image in other row 
take a look of this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sarfarazdesigner/T9nxq/

I have describe what i have done i have take input type radio and give him `position relative`
and take a another `div` and give him `position absolute` and put it to that perticular `inputs` and by `clicking` on `image` i set `input` to `click` in this am success in getting value but am stuck in
setting stars image help me please and sorry for my english thanks :-)

```
<div class="ratingDiv review">
    <div class="row">
        <label class="lbl">Features : </label>
        <div class="ratingwrap">
            <div style="position:relative;">
                <div class="fkdiv">
                    <input type="radio" id="poor" class="rtchk"  name="Features"  value="1" />
                    <input type="radio" id="average" class="rtchk"  name="Features" value="2" checked="checked" />
                    <input type="radio" id="good" class="rtchk"  name="Features" value="3" />
                    <input type="radio" id="verygood" class="rtchk"  name="Features" value="4" />
                    <input type="radio" id="excellent" class="rtchk"  name="Features" value="5" />
                </div>
                <div class="rateMe" title="Rate Me...">
                    <a id="_1" title="poor" class="hvr"></a>
                    <a id="_2" title="average" class="hvr"></a>
                    <a id="_3" title="good" class="hvr"></a>
                    <a id="_4" title="verygood" class="hvr"></a>
                    <a id="_5" title="excellent" class="hvr"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="rateStatus">this is awesome</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <label class="lbl">Support : </label>
        <div class="ratingwrap">
            <div style="position:relative;">
                <div class="fkdiv">
                    <input type="radio" id="poor" class="rtchk"  name="Support"  value="1" />
                    <input type="radio" id="average" class="rtchk"  name="Support" value="2" checked="checked" />
                    <input type="radio" id="good" class="rtchk"  name="Support" value="3" />
                    <input type="radio" id="verygood" class="rtchk"  name="Support" value="4" />
                    <input type="radio" id="excellent" class="rtchk"  name="Support" value="5" />
                </div>
                <div class="rateMe" title="Rate Me...">
                    <a id="_6" title="poor" class="hvr"></a>
                    <a id="_7" title="average" class="hvr"></a>
                    <a id="_8" title="good" class="hvr"></a>
                    <a id="_9" title="verygood" class="hvr"></a>
                    <a id="_10" title="excellent" class="hvr"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <label class="lbl">Userfriendly : </label>
        <div class="ratingwrap">
            <div style="position:relative;">
                <div class="fkdiv">
                    <input type="radio" id="poor" class="rtchk"  name="Userfriendly"  value="1" />
                    <input type="radio" id="average" class="rtchk"  name="Userfriendly" value="2" checked="checked" />
                    <input type="radio" id="good" class="rtchk"  name="Userfriendly" value="3" />
                    <input type="radio" id="verygood" class="rtchk"  name="Userfriendly" value="4" />
                    <input type="radio" id="excellent" class="rtchk"  name="Userfriendly" value="5" />
                </div>
                <div class="rateMe" title="Rate Me...">
                    <a id="_11" title="poor" class="hvr"></a>
                    <a id="_12" title="average" class="hvr"></a>
                    <a id="_13" title="good" class="hvr"></a>
                    <a id="_14" title="verygood" class="hvr"></a>
                    <a id="_15" title="excellent" class="hvr"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <label class="lbl">Customer Values : </label>
        <div class="ratingwrap">
            <div style="position:relative;">
                <div class="fkdiv">
                    <input type="radio" id="poor" class="rtchk"  name="Customer"  value="1" />
                    <input type="radio" id="average" class="rtchk"  name="Customer" value="2" checked="checked" />
                    <input type="radio" id="good" class="rtchk"  name="Customer" value="3" />
                    <input type="radio" id="verygood" class="rtchk"  name="Customer" value="4" />
                    <input type="radio" id="excellent" class="rtchk"  name="Customer" value="5" />
                </div>
                <div class="rateMe" title="Rate Me...">
                    <a id="_16" title="poor" class="hvr"></a>
                    <a id="_17" title="average" class="hvr"></a>
                    <a id="_18" title="good" class="hvr"></a>
                    <a id="_19" title="verygood" class="hvr"></a>
                    <a id="_20" title="excellent" class="hvr"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <label class="lbl">Reliability : </label>
        <div class="ratingwrap">
            <div style="position:relative;">
                <div class="fkdiv">
                    <input type="radio" id="poor" class="rtchk"  name="Reliability"  value="1" />
                    <input type="radio" id="average" class="rtchk"  name="Reliability" value="2" checked="checked" />
                    <input type="radio" id="good" class="rtchk"  name="Reliability" value="3" />
                    <input type="radio" id="verygood" class="rtchk"  name="Reliability" value="4" />
                    <input type="radio" id="excellent" class="rtchk"  name="Reliability" value="5" />
                </div>
                <div class="rateMe" title="Rate Me...">
                    <a id="_21" title="poor" class="hvr"></a>
                    <a id="_22" title="average" class="hvr"></a>
                    <a id="_23" title="good" class="hvr"></a>
                    <a id="_24" title="verygood" class="hvr"></a>
                    <a id="_25" title="excellent" class="hvr"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <label class="lbl">After Sales Services : </label>
        <div class="ratingwrap">
            <div style="position:relative;">
                <div class="fkdiv">
                    <input type="radio" id="poor" class="rtchk"  name="Services"  value="1" />
                    <input type="radio" id="average" class="rtchk"  name="Services" value="2" checked="checked" />
                    <input type="radio" id="good" class="rtchk"  name="Services" value="3" />
                    <input type="radio" id="verygood" class="rtchk"  name="Services" value="4" />
                    <input type="radio" id="excellent" class="rtchk"  name="Services" value="5" />
                </div>
                <div class="rateMe" title="Rate Me...">
                    <a id="_26" title="poor" class="hvr"></a>
                    <a id="_27" title="average" class="hvr"></a>
                    <a id="_28" title="good" class="hvr"></a>
                    <a id="_29" title="verygood" class="hvr"></a>
                    <a id="_30" title="excellent" class="hvr"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <label class="lbl">Over all Rating : </label>
        <div class="ratingwrap">
            <div style="position:relative;">
                <div class="fkdiv">
                    <input type="radio" id="poor" class="rtchk"  name="rating"  value="1" />
                    <input type="radio" id="average" class="rtchk"  name="rating" value="2" checked="checked" />
                    <input type="radio" id="good" class="rtchk"  name="rating" value="3" />
                    <input type="radio" id="verygood" class="rtchk"  name="rating" value="4" />
                    <input type="radio" id="excellent" class="rtchk"  name="rating" value="5" />
                </div>
                <div class="rateMe" title="Rate Me...">
                    <a title="poor" class="hvr"></a>
                    <a title="average"  class="hvr"></a>
                    <a title="good" class="hvr"></a>
                    <a title="verygood" class="hvr"></a>
                    <a title="excellent" class="hvr"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!--rating review div end here-->
```

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/T9nxq/1/

Comment: what you have done i can't get it. it's same like my code

Comment: when we clicked on any row and select my first rating after this when we go to another row it's select by default where my mouse gone, my problem is this i want to set rated variable false after select it true its very confusing

Comment: How about this? http://jsfiddle.net/T9nxq/4/

Comment: it's working good but :-( it has a little bit problem now when any row is clicked and if we take our mouse to that row the stars fill automatic where our mouse move on that particular row please check it again

Comment: i've checked it but i am unable to make a logic for this if we clicked on a row how to handle this if user take hover again on that row i think we have to locked that particular row if user click on star please help me for make a logic for this

Comment: it's really complicated what you are trying to achieve. You'll have to spend couple hours by yourself for sorting this out.

Comment: thanks for your help i'll doing by myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after a couple of hours i've fixed the issue of stars take a look of this link 
jsfiddle.net/sarfarazdesigner/myLTC/1/
i got what i want and credit goes to @Morpheus and a little bit of my head :-)